# Access form request from Observer laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, model

I am trying to cleanup my controller. I have a lot form fields so I want to use observer to insert for the other model that have relationship with the main model

I have already successfully insert the request to the database in a controller but it seems to long and heavy. See code below

```
function insert(Request $request){

 $bankStatementName = time().'.'.request()->bankStatement->getClientOriginalExtension();
request()->bankStatement->move(public_path('bankStatement'), $bankStatementName);

$identityName = time().'.'.request()->identity->getClientOriginalExtension();
request()->identity->move(public_path('identity'), $identityName);

 $passportName = time().'.'.request()->passport->getClientOriginalExtension();
request()->passport->move(public_path('passport'), $passportName);


 $customer = Customer::find(Auth::user()->id);

 $relations = new Customer_relationship([
                      'kinName' => $request->kinName,
                      'kinGender' => $request->kinGender,
                      'kinEmail' => $request->kinEmail,
                      'kinRelation' => $request->kinRelation,
                      'kinAddress' =>  $request->kinAddress
                  ]);
 $company = new Customer_company([
                'compName' => $request->compName,
                'compEmail' => $request->compEmail,
                'compPhone' => $request->compPhone,
                'compAddress' => $request->compAddress
             ]);
 $bank = new Customer_bank([
             'accNumber' => $request->accNumber,
             'bankName' => $request->bankName,
             'accName' => $request->accName
         ]);
 $document = new Customer_document([
        'identity' => $identityName,
        'bankStatement' => $bankStatementName,
        'passport' => $passportName
    ]);
 $customer->relation()->save($relations);
 $customer->company()->save($company);
 $customer->bank()->save($bank);
 $customer->document()->save($document);


Customer::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'middlename' =>  isset($request->middlename) ? $request->middlename : "",
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'DOB' => $request->DOB,
            'marital' => $request->marital,
            'residential_address' => $request->residential_address,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'state' => $request->state,
            'lga' => $request->lga,
            'nationality' => $request->nationality,
            'complete_registration' => 1 ]);

}
```

So how can I access the form request field from Updating function from observer to do a controller cleanup

Comment: Did you try to typehint `Request $request` in your updating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

If you want to use Observers here, you should start by reading up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers and https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

This will likely work if you have all the data needed on your parent model, since you would just pass that model into the job that was triggered by the observer. If not, then observer/job might not be the best solution in your case. Instead I would probably create some sort of service, where you move the responsibility for creating these relationships. That way you can keep a clean controller level that only calls a service to create the models and then returns the result.

An example of this could be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Something\SomeService;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var SomeService 
     */
    private $someService;

    public function __construct(SomeService $someService)
    {
        $this->someService = $someService;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $request = request();
        $name    = $request->input('name');


        $something = $this->someService->create($name);

        return response()->json(['data' => $something]);
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Models\Something;

class SomeService
{
    public function create(string $name): Something
    {
        // Do whatever in here...
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of how I would do it. Hope it helps you a bit.

If you still want to use a job to take care of this, then I still don't think an observer is the right solution for you, as those are triggered on model events, such as `created`. This mean that you will not have access to the request object at that time, but only was was created (The model). Instead you could dispatch a job directly from the controller/service. That is all described in the queue link I posted at the top of the answer.

Comment: Thanks I actually created a method in the controller later use it in main method